# Rendering value from database directly to my GETORGCHART Plugin

Tags: orgchart

I am using the free downlaoded version of GetOrgChart. I just want to Display the Chart and fill the values directly coming from my database. How can I do that? Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily feed GetOrgChart from json action method. Here is an example: http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Initialize-from-JSON

Answer (score 0):

Though very late, i think this can help other users.

The image object from DB can be converted to base64  string and then rendered to the page by passing the string in place of the URL

If you look at the JSON source, we could see the image URL.
 "Image":"http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart-demos/images/f-3.jpg"

In this context if we were to show fetch and show images from database, we need to convert the image to Base64 string (Images in our system are stored as varbinary). 
The change to json will be something like "Image":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAA..."